# Laravel Homestead & nginx - unable to use the requested resource as a variable

Tags: laravel, nginx, homestead

I am running an older Laravel project that requires PHP 5.6 and I am using Laravel Homestead to run the older version of PHP.

For the development environment I am trying to configure nginx to rewrite image URLs used on the website to the production server so I don't have to download the assets to view the website locally.

Previously I have used the following nginx location rule to rewrite the URL:

```
location ~ ^/en/images/(.*) {
    rewrite ^/en/images/(.*)$ https://live.website/en/images/$1 last;
}
```

In order for Homestead to persist the custom nginx config I have had to create a serve-custom.sh file in the Homestead /scripts directory, and set this in my Homestead.yaml file.

My serve-custom.sh file looks like this

```
declare -A params=$6     # Create an associative array
paramsTXT=""
if [ -n "$6" ]; then
  for element in "${!params[@]}"
do
  paramsTXT="${paramsTXT}
  fastcgi_param ${element} ${params[$element]};"
done
fi

if [ "$7" = "true" ] && [ "$5" = "7.2" ]
then configureZray="
location /ZendServer {
    try_files \$uri \$uri/ /ZendServer/index.php?\$args;
}
"
else configureZray="" .   
fi

block="server {
listen ${3:-80};
listen ${4:-443} ssl http2;
server_name .$1;
root \"$2\";

index index.html index.htm index.php;

charset utf-8;

location / {
    try_files \$uri \$uri/ /index.php?\$query_string;
}

$configureZray

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

access_log off;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/$1-error.log error;

sendfile off;

client_max_body_size 100m;

location ~ ^/en/images/(.*) {
    rewrite ^/en/images/(.*)$ https://live.website/en/images/$1 last;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php$5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME \$document_root\$fastcgi_script_name;
    $paramsTXT

    fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/$1.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/$1.key;
}
"

echo "$block" > "/etc/nginx/sites-available/$1"
ln -fs "/etc/nginx/sites-available/$1" "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/$1"
```

The problem I am having is that when looking in DevTools in Chrome, the actual nginx server name is being inserted instead of the requested file / asset.

Hope this all makes sense. Thanks for any help in advance.